# How to add Auto completion features on Search Bar in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, autocomplete

Hi can anyone please provide me with some document who can help me setting auto completion thing in grails app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help you! [Using Grails With JQuery Autocomplete](http://jay-chandran.blogspot.mx/2011/09/using-grails-with-jquery-autocomplete.html)